# $(\varprojlim_n O_K/p^n) \otimes_{O_K} O_L \cong \varprojlim_n (O_K/p^n \otimes_{O_K} O_L)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of global fields, and $O_K$, $O_L$ be respectively integer rings of $K$, $L$.
Let $p$ be a prime ideal of $O_K$.

When is the canonical homomorphism
$$(\varprojlim_n O_K/p^n) \otimes_{O_K} O_L \to \varprojlim_n (O_K/p^n \otimes_{O_K} O_L)$$
an isomorphism?

I already know that the above map is an isomorphism if $O_L$ is free $O_K$-module. However, $O_L$ is not always free $O_K$-module. In general, is the map an isomorphism?